# Menu links not working on a responsive site - z index issue?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

OK downloaded, a free one page html5 template that uses Twitter Bootstrap - works fine, until I want to change a link in the top menu to go to another page. It doesn't work !

A little research suggests a z index issue - but I can't figure it out.

The menu is thus

```
<nav class="pull-left">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li class="animated wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="0s"><a href="#about" title="More details about our golf club">About Us</a></li>
        <li class="animated wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay=".1s"><a href="http://merseytribe.co.uk/membership-register.html" title="Sign up today for one free month trial at our gold club">Join</a></li>
        <li class="animated wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay=".2s"><a href="#app_features" title="Already a member? Sign in here">Members</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And the site URL is http://merseytribe.co.uk/

Tried all sorts of things and it's driving me crazy !

Thanks, David

Comment: " It doesn't work !" please clarify. Links seem to be working fine. There is definitely no z-index issue here.

Comment: I've changed the second link on the menu 'Join' to go to a different page - unfortunately it doesn't

Comment: That's because this template was meant as a one page template. The links in the top menu probably have some kind of javascript applied to them that prevents the `default` behaviour of the links. Thus staying on the samen page.

Comment: I tried target="_blank" to the Join link, and it worked. I suspect there is a jQuery issue which is causing the problem. it might be trying to find the ID on the page to scroll to that position, rather than redirecting to that page.

Comment: @NileshMahajan Then adding `target="_self"`to the link would probably work.

Comment: @timo: Yes, adding target="_self" also works. :)

Comment: look at your main.js at line 3 : 'Navigation Menu scrollTo'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.location='http://merseytribe.co.uk/membership-register.html'" title="Sign up today for one free month trial at our gold club">Join</a>
```

Try this. it will work. because it is one page theme so all link is working with js. but it is absolute link.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding targe="_self" or target="_blank" to the anchor tag as per your requirement.

```
<a title="Sign up today for one free month trial at our gold club" href="http://merseytribe.co.uk/membership-register.html" target="_self">Join</a>
```